# Want to create custom command and be able to pass arguments to it

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

So I have following command which I using pretty often on server

```
ps aux | grep someword | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

What I want is make alias to this command and be able to pass arguments to it which will be placed in place of `someword`
like this

```
killstuff proxy
```

which will result to

```
ps aux | grep proxy | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why so complicated?

```
pkill -f proxy
```

Here, [`pkill`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) takes an argument named `-f` to search for a pattern in the process name (more specifically, `/proc/pid/cmdline`).

You can also tell it to use another signal as in `pkill -9 -f proxy`.

Other than that you want to use a shell function with one parameter – but this is very simplistic and may result in a lot of killed processes if used the wrong way:

```
killstuff() {
  ps aux | grep "$1" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
}
```